# Why "CopyFrom" is used during the creation of the constant Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

During the creation process of the constant Tensor there is the following [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/beb10ceb086fe94a6b1247b45397aafddd47e05d/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py#L162):

```
  tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
      tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
```

`CopyFrom` creates a copy of a newly created Tensor proto. However this looks like waste of resource for coping since `make_tensor_proto`, according to the doc, creates a new object. Would it be more sufficient, just to do next:

```
  tensor_value.tensor =
      tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape)
```

This should not create a new object, plus it is also a valid usage of the OneOf protobuf fields.

Comment: Good point, I am removing the CopyFrom and performing a test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign a proto to a field of a proto as explained in this doc: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated

> You cannot assign a value to an embedded message field. Instead, assigning a value to any field within the child message implies setting the message field in the parent.

If you remove the CopyFrom, you will get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to field "tensor" in protocol message object.
```